# straight camera movement in google earth plugin via Internet Explorer COM

Tags: matlab, com, activex, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have a problem to imitate a straight line in Google Earth Plugin. To imitate the straight line, I invoke a JavaScript method in a HTML Document from MATLAB via COM. (MATLAB as COM- Client and Internet Explorer as COM-Server)

The JavaScript code is below:

```
function UpdateCamera(lat,lon,alt,bearing,pitch,roll) {
  var camera = ge.getView().copyAsCamera(ge.ALTITUDE_ABSOLUTE);

  // set the camera values         
  camera.setLatitude(lat);
  camera.setLongitude(lon);
  camera.setAltitude(alt);
  camera.setHeading(bearing);
  camera.setTilt(pitch);
  camera.setRoll(roll);

  // Set the FlyTo speed
  ge.getOptions().setFlyToSpeed(ge.SPEED_TELEPORT);

  // Update the view in Google Earth  
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(camera);
}
```

And for invoking the JavaScript method, I use this in MATLAB:

```
for i=1:iend
    h.Document.parentWindow.execScript(['tickAnimation(' num2str(cood(i,1)) ',' ...
                                                    num2str(cood(i,2)) ',' ... 
                                                    num2str(cood(i,3)) ',' ...
                                                    num2str(70) ',' ...
                                                    num2str(90) ',' ...
                                                    num2str(0) ');'] , 'JavaScript');

pause(0.01)

end
```

I get the latitude and longitude from the distance, which is the output of a simulation. Using the formula here http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty-direct.html
(this formula is accurate within 0.5mm!)

Unfortunately, I still cannot get a straight movement in Google Earth. The movement forwards consists zig-zag motion. you can see the result here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KS77qORjFh8

The movements upwards is already smooth. the problem now is only the forwards movement.

Looking forward for your inputs.

Regards,
Wan

Comment: how is this different from your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534627/inconsistency-while-invoking-javascript-method-in-internet-explorer-activex-contr

Answer (score 1):

During the movement not only lat/lng of the camera changes but also the heading. So, you need to update the heading as well.

Comment: If you look at the MATLAB code, I do update the heading. Somehow I pasted the old code of the JavaScript. the code is the same, just the function name is now tickAnimation instead of UpdateCamera. 

From Matlab I invoke the method tickAnimation, which containing lat,lon,alt,bearing(which is the heading),pitch and roll.

I set the heading as 70° constant because I think that to go straight, I need to set the heading constant, as what would I do, if I am using a compass.

Or do you mean that the heading's value changes as I move forward?

Comment: When you move to a target on the shortest path, you move along the "great circle". During this movement the heading (bearing) changes. See e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(navigation)#Usage) or google for it. You find a formula to compute the heading e.g. in [Mathforum](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55417.html). The line with constant heading is called the rhumb line - it is not the shortest path.